# How to expose a module from an Electron app to an external module

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, electron-builder

I am creating an Electron app and am using [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/) to package and build the app. Users are able to make plugins for the app *(plugins can be node modules with their own dependencies and such)*. Everything is working fine except the part of the app for exposing the app's API to the plugin.

I created a module in the app for handling the plugins "Plugin-handler" that imports the plugin and also exposes the API to the plugin *(The app's API is just a set of functions and it is bundled with the app)*.

The dilemma is that the user should be able to place a plugin anywhere on their machine and the app does not know the path before the build. Consequently, I excluded the "plugin-handler" module in the Electron-builder config so it does not bundle with the Webpack. Now I need to find the right way to expose the API to the plugin.

**Here is how I am doing it now, to load the plugins and passing the API:**

```
// In the Plugin-handler module
const API = require('api')
const plugin = require('path-to-plugin')( API )
```

- *path-to-plugin is added by the user in the app when they import their plugin.*

As seen above, currently I pass the API to the plugin as an argument, which is not ideal, instead, **I need a way to exposing the API module** *(or any other module that is bundled in the APP)* **to the plugin so users can access it in their plugin like below**:

```
// In the plugin 
const { arg1, arg2,... } = require('api')
```

I've seen apps doing this, and allowing users to access their API in their plugins, but since I am new to all this, I may be doing things wrong, so please do be kind, and thank you for the help!

**I drew a simple chart for better portraying the question:**
[image: The app's structure]